# The priority of require () 's parameter to determine the file-extension in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I am learning node.js

for example, I try

```
var server = require("./myserver.js");
```

and

```
var server = require("./myserver");
```

Both of these two casework.

what if I have another file with the same name?
e.g myserver.json, myserver.node
, will it always search .js at first?

From one of the answerers in my previous question,
he mentions
only load the .json file if you explicitly add the .json extension to the require-call. So if you leave the extension, it always loads the .js file.

will this rule also suit to .node file?

Comment: I believe you only need to specify the file if it is not a js file.

Comment: https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2169-where-does-node-js-and-require-look-for-modules.htm   for details on search path

Comment: The entire rules for `require()` are [here](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together) in the nodejs doc.  The whole search process is fully described there.  Time to do some reading.

Answer (score 4):

If the exact filename is not found, then Node.js will attempt to load the required filename with the added extensions: .js, .json, and finally .node. You can check node_js docs for detailed explanation. https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_file_modules

Answer (score 0):

Yes, If you will not provide the extension of the file, Then, **it will first look at the JS file**, since **JS is by default**